# What's a good insult for a Tech Priest to say to a non-mechanical entity?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I have found myself with my crew in an unfortunate circumstance, and it has developed to the point of high tensions, when everything and anything could go wrong if handled... *indelicately*.

However before you go ranting on about *"Why the hell would you want to do that?"*, my character; the Tech Priest, has a deep seated hatred for the dark Eldar standing on the other side of the table, so by my point of view, "indelicately" is definitely at the forefront of his mind right now.

So what would be a good insult for the Tech Priest to spit at anything that isn't a machine?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a list of ideas, rather than looking for a single, definitive answer.

Comment: Did you mean- what would be a fluffy insult for the Tech Priest to spit at the Dark Eldar?

Comment: @AlexDawson Yeah, along those lines :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a lot of computer speak in the insult. E.G: in Dan Abnetts book Titanicus, one of the characters uses the phrase "very error shunt abort" to mean pissed off.

In many books, the Tech Priest tends to be an over exaggerated version of Spock and yet can still get angry about something. In my experience, only a few books have covered Tech Priests with any level of skill. A reoccurring insult though is usually about how much of the other person is still flesh. An Eldar then, would be the lowest of the low because of how much they rely on organic materials.

So you could try: Useless fleshbag that should reboot in safe mode before his systems end in a blue screen of death... for instance. The weirder and crapper it sounds the better.

Comment: Have a small list of appropriate computer terminology repurposed as moral judgements, the more esoteric the better, but prioritize them in terms of how easily they roll off the tongue - you want your insult to sound like something people yell when angry, and complex things rarely survive in that context.